# Crystal: Default value as fallback (from Database)

Tags: crystal-reports, report

We are planning to use CR2013 for creating invoices and other documents for our customers.
Report-Generation will be initiated by JAVA-Call.

In genral all documents have the same basic layout but for some of our customers we need special texts in the Footer of the document.

The idea was, to have 3 tables:

- customer
- invoice-data
- custom-texts

All three tables could be reverenced and connected by `customer_id`.

Custom-Texts should now contain a row with `customer_id = 0` which will act as a fallback if customer-specific texts are not provided.

Example:

```
Custom-Texts

ID    | customer_id | Footertext 1 | Footertext 2
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
0     | 0           | Defaulttext  | Defaulttext
1     | 44          | Special Text | Special Text    
2     | 78          | Special 2    | Special
```

So for customers with id 44 and 78 the special texts are taken, for all others the texts provided in `id = 0`.

Is this possible and how can we do?

Answer (score 0):

create a formula in footer and write below code. Below code assumes both `Default Text` and `Special Text` coming from databse

```
if customer_id=0
then Footertext 1
else Footertext 1
```

above code compares the id to 0 if yes returns default text and if no returs special text

follow the same process for Footer2 aswell.

Edit---------------------------------------

place a sub report in the footer.

in that sub report create a group with customer ID. and the place the below formula in detail section

```
Footertext 1
```

now just display detail in subreport and supress all other sections.

Comment: Does this really work out? 

We will never have a customer with id=0 as 0 is representing all user that are not specified separately (like id=44 in Example).

So Customer 44 will get Specialtext and all others will get Default.... and i need to extend this list by additional IDs of cause.

Comment: if you never get a customer with id=0 then always your control will go to else part and required data will be displayed.

Comment: i just edited the description do make more clear, we may have hunderes of special-texts for different IDs.